# How to read and source capacitors on a xbox one x motherboard?

Tags: capacitor

I found out that one of the capacitors on my xbox one x motherboard is blown. I'm totally new to reading capcitors. How do I read these and when sourcing them are they all the same even if the colors are different?

[image]

Comment: I don't see any blown capacitors in the picture. Are you sure that it's blown? How did you conclude that?

Comment: You should try to source your electronic components from a 'real' electronic parts distributor like [Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/capacitors/aluminum-polymer-capacitors/69?FV=mu270%C2%B5F%7C2049%2Cmu470%C2%B5F%7C2049%2Cmu16V%7C2079%2Cmu20V%7C2079%2Cmu25V%7C2079%2C-8%7C69&quantity=10&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=25), or [Mouser](https://www.mouser.com/Passive-Components/Capacitors/Aluminum-Electrolytic-Capacitors/Aluminum-Organic-Polymer-Capacitors/_/N-bmaieZ1yzvvqx?P=1z0wriyZ1z0wrk5Z1z0x6edZ1yx4aw3Z1yzv881Z1yqjoa3&Ns=Pricing|0), instead of random ebay sellers...

Answer (score 1):

I think someone on here (Andy or Tony?) told me a while back the different colours represent different compositions.

For SMD caps, you will want to measure the base dimensions and case height (height not so important if you have enough clearance) since the bases are standardized.

For leaded caps, measure the diameter and height and make sure you have enough space, but the most important thing is to measure the lead spacing/pitch.

Your caps seems pretty clearly labelled as 16V, 470uF and 270uF, 16V.

Different manufacturers list things differently.

I think CDE/Illinois are the people who made your caps. They make a ULR cap with the same labeling scheme.

https://www.illinoiscapacitor.com/pdf/seriesDocuments/ULR%20series.pdf

But how do you know they are blown?

Comment: I read somewhere these go bad internally and affect the xbox one x hard drives some how. I actually extracted these from another board and put it in the board that needed it and it fixed the underlying issue. I replaced all of them as I wasn't sure how do I even test these if they work or not.

Comment: I checked on ebay: https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=Nichicon+470uf+16v+ulr&_sacat=0&LH_TitleDesc=0&_osacat=0&_odkw=Nichicon+470uf+16v --- Many of them are different colors, but the specs are the same. Does it matter?

Comment: @Patoshiパトシ Type can matter. On something high performance like an XBox the circuits it is being used with might depend on the high performance specs of the capacitor and it possibly won't work with a lesser cap.I don't buy caps off E-bay. Not trustworthy and often not enough info. At the very least you want to replace a polymer cap with another polymer cap, and not a crappy regular electrolytic.

Answer (score 1):

Those are solid polymer capacitors.
470 means C=470uF same as 270 means C=270uF.
They're polarized that's why they're marked with the colored side (It is the cathode)

To test if they work or not you need to extract it from the board.
Then you discharge the capacitor (just connect a resistor to it). Use your multimeter in capacitance measurement mode and that's it.

Comment: I'm checking ebay: https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=470uf+16v+polymer&_sacat=0&LH_TitleDesc=0&_osacat=0&_odkw=470uf+16v+solid+polymer they don't have the exact same looking ones. Do I just need to make sure it is the same uF and V only?

Comment: Are you sure 470 wouldn't mean 47 μF? I would think 470 μF would be marked as 471.

Comment: That's not how it works on solid polymer capacitors. 470 means 470uF, if you want a 47uF capacitor the mark is 47

Comment: @Patoshiパトシ I haven't bought any components on Ebay. I'd recommend you to buy from an electronics components distributor